# How to find keys whose values are the same (values are also dictionaries)

Tags: python, graph-theory

There is a graph (please see the example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJEm1.png)) and I am using a dictionary to store the adjacency matrix:

```
{A:{B:a, C:a, D:a}, B:{A:a, E:b}, C:{A:a}, D:{A:a}, E:{B:b}}
```

where uppercase letters are nodes, lowercase letters are edges.

I am trying to find nodes who have the same adjacency (C, D in this example). How can I implement it? Changing the data structure of the adjacency matrix is fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: Are the nodes objects or strings?

Comment: @Jeppe There are represented by integers

Comment: The chosen representation **is wrong**, because the (**oriented**) graph can't be reconstructed from the dictionary info.

Comment: @CristiFati Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Either have edges as keys, and for each one have its cost, source and destination nodes, either have nodes as keys and for each one have 2 sets of edges (in and out - each edge with its cost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the graph and for each two distinct nodes check if adjacency details of those are the same, by using `==` operator.

```py
graph = {
    'A': {'B': 'a', 'C': 'a', 'D': 'a'},
    'B': {'A': 'a', 'E': 'b'},
    'C': {'A': 'a'},
    'D': {'A': 'a'},
    'E': {'B': 'b'},
}

res = {}
for u, u_adj in graph.items():
    res.setdefault(u, [])
    for v, v_adj in graph.items():
        if u != v and u_adj == v_adj:
            res[u].append(v)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your Problem then this can be a Solution for you if your data type is a Dictionary:

```
    temp = {}
    for key, value in your_dictionary.items():
       temp.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
```

if you then want to retrieve the keys who have the same values from a Dictionary then you can use this:

```
    res = [values for key, values in temp.items() if len(values) > 1]
```

Comment: `value` is a `dict` which can't be hashed or used as key, right?

Comment: indeed, the code above throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`, since the values of the main dict in the question are also dicts.